# cannot resolve overloaded function ‘swap’ based on conversion to type

Tags: c++

can anyone fix the error in this code?

```
# include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void bubble_sort (int a[], int size);
float bubble_sort (float b[], int size);
int read (int a[], int size);
float read (float b[], int size);
void display (int a[], int size);
void display (float b[], int size);


   int main()

{

     int const size=10;

    int a[10];

    int b[10];

    read (a,size);

    read (b,size);

    bubble_sort(a,size);

    bubble_sort(b,size);

    display(a,  size);

    display(b, size);

    return 0;
}

    int read (int a[], int size)
        {
            cout<<"Enter the integer values:";
          for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
                 cin>>a[i];

        }

    float read (float b[], int size)
        {
             cout<<"Enter the float values :";
          for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
                  cin>>b[i];
        }

    void bubble_sort (int a[], int size)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
                if (a[j]>a[j + 1])
                {
                    swap = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                    a[j + 1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }

    float bubble_sort (float b[], int size)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
                if (b[j]>b[j + 1])
                {
                    swap = b[j];
                    b[j] = b[j + 1];
                    b[j + 1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }


    void display (int a[], int size)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
            cout<<a[i]<<" ";

        }

    void display (float b[], int size)
        {
                  cout<<endl;
            for(int i=0 ;i<size; i++)
                cout<<b[i]<<" ";
        }
```

compiler shows that overloaded function with no contextual type information. but i need to use the overloaded function. how can i solve that?

```
In function ‘void bubble_sort(int*, int)’:
error: overloaded function with no contextual type information
                 swap = a[j];
                      ^
error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘swap’ based on conversion to type ‘int’
                 a[j + 1] = swap;
```

Comment: try function template instead

Comment: _'compiler shows that overloaded function with no contextual type information'_ How does it? Error text?

Comment: You're using `swap` and you haven't declared it. There happens to be a `std::swap` function template.

Answer (score 3):

In `bubble_sort`, you are doing `swap = a[j];`, but you haven't actually declared a `swap` variable. It seems that you may have intended to do something like:

```
float swap;
```

You're getting the error you're getting because there is a `std::swap` function and you have done `using namespace std;`. This is precisely one of the reasons why you shouldn't do `using namespace std;`. If you didn't do it, your error would be much clearer:

```
error: ‘swap’ was not declared in this scope
```

Note also that you're not returning anything from your `read` and `bubble_sort` functions.

Answer (score 1):

1.Both of your arrays a[] and b[] are integer arrays.

2.in function int read(int*, int) and float read(int*, int), you are not returning anything.

3.And the compiler says that you are overloading **swap** with no contextual information because swap is a pre-defined function in iostream and you have not even defined this variable.